# growth rate of quadratic exponential sums with monomial coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, exponential-sums

What is the growth rate of $$S_d(M)=\sum_{n=1}^M n^d e\left(\frac{n^2}{2M}\right)$$
where $M$ is an even integer.
My numerical experiments show that
$$\frac{S_d(M)}{M^{d+\frac{1}{2}}}\approx e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}\cdot C(M)$$
where $C(M)\in \mathbf{R},$ $|C(M)|\le O(1).$

Comment: What is $e(...)$ ? And what do you mean by $\approx$ when complex numbers are involved?

Comment: look up (quadratic) Gauss sums and use summation by parts; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum

Comment: I think that there is some imaginary number $i$ missing in the definition of $S_d(M)$.

Comment: @RolandBacher The OP is using the notation $e(z) = e^{2 \pi i z}$, so I don't think any complex numbers are missing.

Comment: have you tried Poisson summation into the stationary phase method? I guess that might be what @Conrad is saying implicitly, I just didn’t see a way to treat the partial sums you’d face in partial summation using just knowledge of Gauss sums but admittedly I didn’t think too hard about it

Comment: Let's keep this one open please!